# useState is not updating immediately

Tags: reactjs

1. I am trying to assign values to my 2 different states(**credit and
   debit**) and Calculate the states's answer and assign it to 3rd
   state(balance). My balance state is not updating immediately, on
   first change it shows the initial value.
2. The solution i want is to have **Calculated value of (credit - debit)** and store in
   **Balance** State

`

```
function App() {

  const [credit, setCredit] = useState(0);
  const [debit, setDebit] = useState(0);
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0); 

  const [records, setRecords] = useState([
    {
      credit: 1200,
      debit: 0,
      balance: 1200,
    },
    {
      credit: 1000,
      debit: 0,
      balance: 1000,
    },
  ]);

  const getInfo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setBalance(credit - debit);  //<- Not updated on very first change

    setRecords([...records, 
      {
        credit: credit,
        debit: debit,
        balance: balance,
      },
    ]);
    setCredit(0);
    setDebit(0);
    setBalance(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <label>Credit</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={credit}
          onChange={(e) => setCredit(e.target.value)}
        />
        <label>Debit</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={debit}
          onChange={(e) => setDebit(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={getInfo}>
          SAVE
        </button>
      </form>

      {records.map((record) => (
        <p>
           credit:{record.credit},debit:{record.debit} balance:{record.balance}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for first time updation you might like to keep your code in `useEffect`.
it will solve the problem.

Comment: This information is useful and done with first attmpt

Answer (score 0):

React state updates are asynchronous. When you do *setBalance(credit-debit)* in getInfo, it does not update balance immediately. State updates are also often clubbed together by react, so since you do setBalance(0) after, it gets set as 0 directly.
It isn't advisable to keep computed properties in state, you could just do

```
    setRecords([...records, 
      {
        credit: credit,
        debit: debit,
        balance: credit - debit,
      },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You default value of `balance` is `0`

```
const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);
```

And on first use you don't update the value:

```
setBalance(credit - debit); // 0 - 0 = 0;
```